# wrong number or types of arguments calling a procedure from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

logged as the user CC_LOPES I have this procedure:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY            "P_MSG_HOTEL" AS

  function parse_msg(p_id in number, p_msg in varchar2) return number is
  ...
end;
```

That I try to execute from Oracle SQL Developer with

```
 EXECUTE P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg(596210657, '@S,358639058787154;E,10;D,05102017145210,05102017145210;G,4046393,51206983,258,8;M,4709;S,0;IO,1,0,0;DI,79DEAD60');
```

I got this error:

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :
BEGIN P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg(596210657, '@S,358639058787154;E,10;D,05102017145210,05102017145210;G,4046393,51206983,258,8;M,4709;S,0;IO,1,0,0;DI,79DEAD60'); END;
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 126:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PARSE_MSG'
ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 126:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am really excited to know incase you really got the `error` you mentioned in your question.

Ideally you must had got something like:

```
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'PARSE_MSG' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

But you posted :

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 1 del comando :
BEGIN P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg(596210657, '@S,358639058787154;E,10;D,05102017145210,05102017145210;G,4046393,51206983,258,8;M,4709;S,0;IO,1,0,0;DI,79DEAD60'); END;
Informe de error -
ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 126:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PARSE_MSG'
ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 126:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

This looks quiet misleading.

I did the below demo to show what i meant.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE P_MSG_HOTEL
AS
   FUNCTION parse_msg (p_id IN NUMBER, p_msg IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY P_MSG_HOTEL
AS
   FUNCTION parse_msg (p_id IN NUMBER, p_msg IN VARCHAR2)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      RETURN 1;
   END;
END;
```

On execution the way you showed it gives the error which say :

```
EXECUTE P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg(596210657,
'@S,358639058787154;E,10;D,05102017145210,05102017145210;G,4046393,51206983,258,8;M,4709;S,0;IO,1,0,0;DI,79DEAD60');
```

Error

```
    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00221: 'PARSE_MSG' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

This clearly means `Oracle` is not able to identify your function while execution. 
However when i do like:

```
SQL> 
select  P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg(596210657, '@S,358639058787154;E,10;D,05102017145210,05102017145210;G,4046393,51206983,258,8;M,4709;S,0;IO,1,0,0;DI,79DEAD60') as col
 from dualSQL>   2  
  3  /

       COL
----------
         1
```

I get the output.

Or if i use an Anonymous block i get the result.

```
SQL> DECLARE
   x   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   x :=
      P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg (
         596210657,
         '@S,358639058787154;E,10;D,05102017145210,05102017145210;G,4046393,51206983,258,8;M,4709;S,0;IO,1,0,0;DI,79DEAD60');
  2     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (x);
END;
/  
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, in short, you cannot use the function the way you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't execute the `function` directly . either do it inside `DBMS_OUTPUT`

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

EXEC DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg(arg1,arg2));
```

Or run a query with function in select to get the output.

```
select P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg(arg1,arg2) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use execute command to execute a function, the function return some value that needs to be captured somewhere, Use anonymous block:

```
declare 
  f_return number;
begin
  f_return := P_MSG_HOTEL.parse_msg(596210657, '@S,358639058787154;E,10;D,05102017145210,05102017145210;G,4046393,51206983,258,8;M,4709;S,0;IO,1,0,0;DI,79DEAD60');
end;
/
```